# Azure table query partial partitionkey guid match

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have the below PartitionKey and want to find it via a "EndsWith" "092a2dca-7107-4859-a129-e590ebd86614" query.

e306cdfc-f573-490c-937b-c283f2d61e6c|092a2dca-7107-4859-a129-e590ebd86614

Is there a way to do this via the Compare string method which is supported?

Comment: I don't think the StartsWith or EndsWith commands are supported by the API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894031.aspx

Comment: I suppose you could store your guid in the reverse order?

Comment: You can do a StartsWith, though only indirectly by combining the greater-than and less-than operators. You cannot do an EndsWith query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the azure table storage query equivalent of T-sql's LIKE command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660250/what-is-the-azure-table-storage-query-equivalent-of-t-sqls-like-command)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no.

Do not do a partial look up on a Partition Key, that results in a regular old table scan.

Comment: I guess the same would be true on RowKey but for a smaller dataset?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  Items in table storage are effectively stored in PartionKey, RowKey order.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest watching this cloud cover episode where Jai Haridas walks through [designing for scale in windows azure storage](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Episode-82-Designing-for-Scale-with-Windows-Azure-Storage)