# Azure Storage Table design with multiple query points

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have the following Azure Storage Table.

**PositionData table:**

```
PartitionKey: ClientID + VehicleID 
RowKey: GUID 
Properties:  ClientID, VehicleID, DriverID, Date, GPSPosition
```

Each vehicle will log up to 1,000,000 entities per year per client. Each client could have thousands of vehicles.  So, I decided to partition by `ClientID` + `VehicleID` so to have small, manageable partitions.  When querying by `ClientID` and `VehicleID`, the operation performs quickly because we are narrowing the search down to one partition.

**PROBLEM:**

The problem here is that sometimes I need to query on only `ClientID` and `DriverID`.  Because it's not possible to perform partial PartitionKey comparisons, every single partition will need to be scanned.  This will kill performance.

I can't have a PartitionKey with all `ClientID`, `VehicleID` and `DriverID` because queries will only ever query on `VehicleID` OR `DriverID`, never both.

**SOLUTION 1:**

I considered having a value stored elsewhere which represented a VehicleID and DriverID pair, and then having a `ClientID + VehicleDriverPairID` PartitionKey, but that would result in hundreds of thousands of partitions and there will be much unioning of data between partitions in my code.

**SOLUTION 2:**

Have a partition for `Client + VehicleID` and another partition for `Client + DriverID`.  This means that updating the table is twice as much work (two updates) but both queries will be fast.  Also there will be redundant data.

Do any of these solutions sound viable?  Other solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should duplicate the records, as in solution 2. And I suggest to keep a copy where each record is in it's own partition, so partitioned by VehiculeId as well, this will making updating all the copies easier, starting from vehicleid and propagating to the others.

Storing data is really cheap, querying is a pita unless you store it correctly up front. So my advice is: Duplicate!

Comment: PS: here is a white paper that shows the internals of storage: http://sigops.org/sosp/sosp11/current/2011-Cascais/printable/11-calder.pdf It explains how partitioning and repartitioning works, basically if you don't specify a full partitionkey you're highly likely to have to fan out one day.

Comment: It does seem like the best solution, but isn't storing redundant data highly frowned upon?  It opens the road to inconsistencies.

Comment: We've all been subject to abuse by the third normal form people for way to long :) No, you will not be frowned upon, unless by dba's and professors at the uni, but hey it's a storage system, not a relational db.

Comment: Yeah, I have had the relational model drilled into me for too long :).  My only concern now is that my C# `TableEntity` type only has one `PartitionKey` property.  I will need to create my own repository interface to handle the double insert.

Comment: Remember that inserts/updates across partitionkeys are never transactional! So if the second update gets rejected, the first will have passed. Personally I separate each update in time by putting a message on a queue and handle it separatly, this gives me automatic retry when a transient failure occurs.

Answer (score 1):

> Because it's not possible to perform partial PartitionKey comparisons,
>   every single partition will need to be scanned.

Not really true. If your partition key is for example (literally) `ClientID$VehicleID`, you  could scan for `PartitionKey gt 'ClientID$' and PartitionKey lt 'ClientID%'` (works because `(Char)($+1)` is `%`. This would scan only partitions that start with ClientID.

Comment: [Apparently partial searches on the PartitionKey result in full table scans anyway.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796631/azure-table-query-partial-partitionkey-guid-match)

Comment: Ah, interesting... sorry for misleading answer.

Comment: Now I am not sure.  According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh508997.aspx) which is endorsed by Microsoft, there might not be a full table scan.  Look under the heading "Determining Queries"

Comment: That linked question was in regards to doing a query for "Ends With", not "Starts With", the original answer was good.

Comment: I am sure,its not full table scan. 
http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Episode-82-Designing-for-Scale-with-Windows-Azure-Storage In this video, Jai Haridas (The architect of azure storage) explaining about the partialkey searching

Comment: Then I will un-strikethrough my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears here that the RowKey is a meaningless GUID, simply for uniqueness, it would be possible to replace/enhanced this and come up with the following.

Every insert is a 2 entity insert into the same partition and hence can be batched, such that both succeed or both fail, ensuring consistency. Note values in [] are optional.

```
PartitionKey = ClientID  
RowKey = [Prefix] + VehicleID + [Suffix]
```

and

```
PartitionKey = ClientID  
RowKey = [Prefix] + DriverID + [Suffix]
```

If the `VehicleID` an `DriverID` are not unique between themselves, they can be made unique by adding a prefix, say "V" and "D".

If uniqueness on the RowKey is desired, it can be suffixed by the date, if sufficient, or by a GUID as done currently.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I am using the RowKey to reference the entity in our core relational database

Comment: In that case, it can be used as the Suffix. You will be able to search by Client, Client + Vehicle, Client + Driver and Client+(Driver|Vehicle) + GUID.

Comment: Given the size of the data I wouldn't have thought that just using the ClientID as PK wouldn't be great for write performance as the partition gets big.  I'd go the other way PK = Padded ClientId + GUID (so the write is still in the same partition and can be batched, each partition is small for fast writes, you can still query by client) RK = [Prefix] + DriverId/VehicleId

Comment: I do not believe a few million entries per partition is too large. (As an aside I would stripe the data by year so that a table would only contain data for a single calendar year. Also easy to drop old data … simply delete the table). Further, your  proposal will not allow optimal retrieve for a query of say all drivers for a client since the GUID would come in the way. You would have a range for PartitionKey and an exact match for the RowKey.  Optimal for a query on both PartitionKey and RowKey would be an exact match on PartitionKey + an exact or range match for RowKey.

Comment: @Lucifure: How would I perform those searches if I can't do partial RowKey comparisons?  Thanks

Comment: You can do partial RowKey comparisons within the same partition, but partial PartitionKey comparisons may be inefficient since 2 logically adjacent partitions may be on different nodes. (The key word here is optimal / efficient). Best to model your approach using some data and determining what each query would look like. If you are not specifying the most significant characters of the PartitionKey + the RowKey, the query would most likely result in a table scan. (I look at the PartitionKey+RowKey as a single composite key and determine if the most significant chars are involved in the query)