# Azure Table Storage - RowKey design for ordered data

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I store large quantities of GPS data in storage tables.  Each partition can reach up to 1 million entities.  Each GPS entity that is inserted into the table is actually sequential to the previous data inserted, so order matters.

Sometimes I need to perform the following query:

> ***Get the previous/next 3 GPS entities from the current entity (within the same partition).***

Options for RowKey design:

1. **Create an incrementing integer.**  But how do I track what the current size of the table is?  There is no way to get table row count, or to get the last inserted row.
2. **Use DateTime Ticks.**  But how do get the previous/next entity using ticks?

I'm using the SDK version 2.0 in C#.

Comment: "Get the previous/next 3 GPS entities from the current entity"  -- Is this within the same Partition Key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a super cool problem to solve.

If your job was to only find entries that are EITHER after or before the given entry, this would be simple, as you could just take the DateTime.Now.Ticks or (DateTime.Max.Ticks - DateTime.Now.Ticks) as the RowKey and use "Take" command on your queries to find the nearest X records.

However, since you need to find nearest locations that are either after or before a given location's ID, here is one design pattern I think may work for your RowKeys:

- You will want save two entities for every GPS location.  Entities' data should be the same except that the row keys would be different
- One entity will have a RowKey of: DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks and have a prefix say: "A" (ascending)
- The other entity will have a RowKey of: DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks and have a 
  prefix character, say: "D" (descending)

For example, you have 7 locations, Location1..thru..Location7  I've given them random Tick values from 01 thru 99 (for simplicity's sake).  Imagine that MaxTicks is 100.  This would make our table contain the following data:

**Rowkey, Entity Data**

- A----01, Location1
- A----50, Location2
- A----55, Location3
- A----66, Location4
- A----67, Location5
- A----90, Location6
- A----99, Location7
- D----01, Location7
- D----10, Location6
- D----33, Location5
- D----34, Location4
- D----45, Location3
- D----50, Location2
- D----99, Location1

Now, for every entity, you can easily calculate its "opposite" Rowkey entity.  (Simply subtract its RowKey from DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks and flip the prefix from A to D or from D to A)

Thus, if you need 2 entities that are before Location3, simply issue the query to take 2 entities from the table where RowKey is greater than "D----45" and smaller than "D----99" (max).  And if you need to take 2 rows after Location3, simply issue a Take 2 where RowKey is greater than "A----55" and less than "A-----99" (max).
Issuing the "less than" criteria is important, so that you dont accidentally run into the "D"s when you're querying against "A"s.

Update/Insert both sets of entities within batch transactions to guarantee that both or none make it into the table and "voila".

The downside to this approach is that you will have to pay for twice the storage.

Hope this helps and is not too confusing

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  I am already having to 'duplicate' data because of [multi query points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133968/azure-storage-table-design-with-multiple-query-points).  This means 4 versions of the same data.  From a relational point of view, this would be terrible.  I'm still trying to wrap my head around designing data for NoSQL.  Data storage is essentially very cheap with Azure, so I think I will go with your suggestion.

Comment: Another option would be to have the redundant partitions only store a column called RowKeyReference which would have the RowKey for the entity in the 'master' partition.  This would save on data costs... but it does have a relationship element to it.  Opinions?

Comment: It depends how many relative entities you need to pick up at a time.  You will do individual queries for those.  (Albeit fast queries).  If you need "a lot" of nearby entities, I'd go with a single query approach... otherwise, it might not be a bad idea to store references only and then get real entities in 2ndary calls.

Comment: You may use '(DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks).ToString("d19")' formatting in rowkey, as it is sorted as string not integers