# filter type %like% for specific field in Storage table Azure

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

Is possible to use a filter type %like % in a query to StorageTable Azure?

or is there some equivalent for this type of search.

```
var clausula = "(PartitionKey eq 'aplicacion1') and (tipoEvento like '%Sistema%')";

        TableQuery<AuditoriaEntidad> consulta = new TableQuery<AuditoriaEntidad>().Where(clausula);
```

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Azure Storage Table only supports eq, ne, gt, ge, lt, le. (See doc [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894031.aspx))

You can leverage

```
PropertyA ge "SomePrefix" and PropertyA lt "SomePrefiy"
```

to query entities whose PropertyA starts with "SomePrefix".

Answer (score 1):

Azure Table Storage don't support 'like' to query data. If you want to use a filter type %like % in a query, the best choice is that you can select this type data based on specific partition key. In other words, you can use this value as partition key. Meanwhile, there has a same issue post:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/15660675/4836342
Please refer to it.